# Why does this block not run when it is stored in a proc?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning ruby and trying to get a better understanding of Blocks, Yield, Procs and Methods and I stumbled upon this example on using yield.

```
def calculation(a, b)
   yield(a, b)
end

x = calculation(5,6) do|a,b|
a + b
end

puts "#{x}"
```

From what I understand Procs are object that holds a pointer to Blocks. And Blocks need a method to work in the first place. Also, from the way yield is used, I assume yield jumps to the block immediately after the method call.

I assume the code runs this way: calculation(5,6) calls the method calculation(). when the yield instruction executes, a and b are passed to the block after calculation(5,6). To experement and get a better understand I tried doing this.

```
def calculation(a, b)
   yield(a, b)
end

ankh = Proc.new do |a,b|
   a + b
end

x = calculation(5,6) *ankh
```

The error says that no block is given to calculation(). But aren't we giving calculation(5,6) the block ankh? Hopefully my question isn't too confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the line `x = calculation(5,6) *ankh`. To pass a method as a block, you use the `&`-operator.

```
x = calculation(5,6,&ankh)
```

Comment: I see. You say "to pass a method as a block", so is that whole `ankh == Proc.new {}` called a method as well? I thought that was the block.  The examples talking about methods I found on Google used `def end`.  I think I'm getting the terminology mixed up.

Comment: Yes you are right, `Proc.new` preserves a block to be called afterwards, which is called a closure or lambda expression. I used the word method because the `&`-operator isn't limited to a block at all, but can for example be used with symbols to call methods on the argument. e.g. `[1,2].collect(&:even?)` -> `[false, true]`

Answer (score 1):

First off: what you wrote doesn't make any sense. Think about it: what does

```
calculation(5, 6) * ankh
```

mean? Or, more abstractly, what does

```
foo * bar
```

mean? Does `2 * 3` really mean "call `2` and pass `3` as a block"?

> The error says that no block is given to calculation(). But aren't we giving calculation(5,6) the block ankh?

No, `ankh` is not a block, it's a [`Proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html). A block is a purely syntactic construct. Most importantly, a block is not an object, so you simply cannot store it in a variable at all. You also cannot pass it as a normal argument to a method, you have to pass it as a separate "special" block argument. Blocks do not exist independent from method calls.

There *is*, however, a way of "converting" a `Proc` into a block: the `&` ampersand unary prefix operator:

```
x = calculation(5, 6, &ankh)
# => 11
```

This tells Ruby to take the `Proc` ankh and turn it into a block. In fact, this mechanism is much more general than that, because you can even pass an object which is *not* a `Proc` and Ruby will first call `to_proc` on that object to allow it to convert itself to a `Proc`.

For example, [`Method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html) implements [`to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-to_proc), so you can pass `Method`s as blocks:

```
def ankh(a, b) a + b end

x = calculation(5, 6, &method(:ankh))
# => 11
```

Also, [`Symbol`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html) implements [`to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc):

```
x = calculation(5, 6, &:+)
# => 11
```

Lastly, [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) implements [`to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-to_proc) as well.

And, of course, you can write your own objects that implement `to_proc`:

```
def (ankh = Object.new).to_proc
  -> *args { "I was called with arguments #{args.inspect}!" }
end

x = calculation(5, 6, &ankh)
# => 'I was called with arguments [5, 6]!'
```